# Why am I getting msvp140_1.dll, vcruntime140.dll, ucrtbased.dll file missing, when they are in my path?

Tags: java, c++, dll, jde

I have both the JDE and JDK installed, I can find the dlls in my PATH and JAVA_HOME Paths, I have rebooted.

Can anyone suggest some troubleshooting, the fact that more than one file is not being found looks to indicate a single issue, and that they are present (actually, ucrtbased.dll is not present and that is usually a C++ redis problem related to Visual Studio v15)

Comment: If it ends in d before the .dll this is a debug runtime which should only exist on machines that have Visual Studio installed.

Comment: To expound on drescherjm's comment, the debug libraries are **not** redistributable and do not have a *redist* installer from Microsoft.

Comment: Maybe you're mixing 32/64 bit versions?

Comment: Use release builds of the program if you're not developing the program. The missing DLLs are unrelated to Java itself.

Comment: @drescherjm- thanks, that helps

Comment: @rustyx - gold. That was the problem